# How to send Grid as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics

I have an web infragistics grid which gets populated from below lines of code.

```
infraGrid.ClearDataSource();
infraGrid.DataSource = objCdtSearchResultsOutput.ResultsList.Tables[0];
infraGrid.DataBind();
```

Whereas in other class I have a method with below signature

```
public void GridOperation(int i,WebDataGrid wdgBillingPackageList)
{
}
```

Now when I am trying to invoke above method with below code

```
Obj.GridOperation(1, this.infraGrid);
```

I am getting `NullPointerException`. Above method call happens in the page where Grid gets populated.
How to get it done ? What is being missed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: try to send datatable as parameter in store procedure

Comment: what is Obj? where did you define and is it initialized?

Comment: @Abion47 This is related to Grid, I am getting exception in page where data is available

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev Obj is Object of Class where `GridOperation` method is defined

Comment: May be Obj not initialized, can you show how did you declare Obj?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `obj.GridOperation` within the correct area of the page lifecycle? Have you set a breakpoint there to check that both `Obj` and `this.infraGrid` have been assigned?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev May be that is the reason, I had it like `GridSelectionOp obj =  Null`. Now updated to `GridSelectionOp obj =  GridSelectionOp ()`

Comment: Well, if you were setting `obj` to `null`, there is no "maybe" about it.

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev Its Gone ! Working as expected. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter what this is related to, because your problem is the NullReferenceException.